How to solve a system of coupled differential equations with time dependent coefficients?
Is there any general method of obtaining analytic solution to the following system of equations
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}x(t) = A(t) x(t) + B(t) y(t) \\
 \frac{d}{dt}y(t) = C(t) y(t) + D(t) x(t)
\end{align}
where coefficients $A,B,C,D$ are arbitrary functions of variable $t$?
